# Dev c++ ConsolePauser.exe is not working and also do not showing any output?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

`ConsolePauser.exe` of the dev c++ compiler do not showing any output even of a simple program like to print hello world. My previous saved programs also not working in it. I want to tell u that program is compiling well but just when i try to run it in console it opens up but do not showing anything just blank. i restarted my pc but same problem occurs again and again. any help would be greatly appeciated?

Comment: Are you running Avast anti-virus?

Comment: yes , but how would u know :)  ?

Comment: The question that I closed this with is about MSVS but the same thing applies to Dev C++.  You will need to exclude your project folder from the anti-virus.